# My treat (general context)

Tags: перевод

Let's say that I want to have a night out on the town with someone that I know is strapped financially, and I want to make it clear that I plan to pay for everything. What can I say that's better than "Я заплачу за всё", which is rude and potentially demeaning? The goal is to make it clear ahead of time that you are offering to take them out all expenses paid, without making them feel uncomfortable.

The English phrase would probably be "my treat" but alternatives are welcome. Google Translate shows "я угощаю" for "my treat" but that just sounds obnoxious, plus it wouldn't seem right if there were no food involved, such as going out to a bar or a movie for example.

To clarify, my question is not about dating etiquette, just a nice, casual way to tell someone - anyone - that you have it covered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Я угощаю` is quite correct and elegant form to mean that you pay for everything. If you invite to something that involves tickets (theater, cinema) it will still be clear, but you may also say `я приглашаю`.

`Я плачу за всё` in this situation is too straightforward. Another straightforward way is `всё за мой счёт`. But both require that the other side not be sensitive to this, nor take it as an offence.

A humorous way would be to say `контора платит` (*[my] company pays*, that person understanding that you mean it's you who pays).

Answer (score 1):

You can say "Расходы на мне".

It's explicit enough without being rude.